# sharing url's on whatsapp desktop app sends you to https by default

Tags: https, desktop-application, whatsapp

Don't know if this is a common thing, but i realized that any url i share through WhatsApp desktop app (Mac & Windows) will send you to https:// by default.
Any one else had this experience?
Adding rules to redirect https traffic to http didn't work for me.
Any clue how to avoid the error messages clients are seeing when any one shares my url on WhatsApp desktop app?
Thank you

Comment: You mean the `http://` in the URL you post gets _replaced_?

Comment: It happens If you share a url without specifying http:// before the domain name, just like erikayelo.com This same domain name sends you to http://erikayelo.com when using mobile app (ios or Android), but when clicking on the link WhatsApp desktop app generates, it sends you to https://erikayelo.com and obviously shows an error message as this web has no secure server.

Comment: That actually is not a URL, it is just a domain name. Why would you expect that the http protocol should be preferred if you do not specify a protocol? Actually https is the preferred choice today for very good reasons ("https everywhere...").

Comment: Because every one not familiarized with protocols and stuff like this, will share on their WhastsApp messages a url as a simple domain, without specifying http:// or https:// In fact my mother did so, as she is not aware of this protocols. On the other hand, if you share a domain and click on it using the ios or android app it will send you to http://

Comment: It is happening again. Now even http:// links are replaced with https:// when clicked or copied.